# what data structure is suiatble to store models

Tags: typescript, data-structures

I want to save a model such as this:

[image]

which is very similar to an electronic circuit:

[image]

and I want to save data as text (for example json or XML or similar portable formats).

What is the best data structure that I can implement in programming (I am using TypeScript) and what is the best way to serialise them into a file and read them back?

Is there any standard for this type of data structures?

Comment: The first example is a graph - a set of vertices V and a set of edges which are a subset of the Cartesian product VxV. The second is an edge labelled graph.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(abstract_data_type)

Comment: @JonGuiton thanks. Is there any implementation that I can use as an example. TS is better, but I am familiar with C++/ C# and Python too.

Comment: Generally you can use a vertex/edge list, adjacency matrix or relational database depending on your particular needs. There is a C++ implementation in the boost library. If you want to do work on electrical circuits you could use a Kruskal matrix https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kruskals-algorithm-simple-implementation-for-adjacency-matrix/.